# Authenticate user in linux with python 3

Tags: python, linux, authentication, python-3.x, pam

I wrote the program that would need to authenticate users using their Linux usernames and passwords. I think it should do with PAM. I have tried searching from google PAM module for python3, but I did not find any. Is there a ready to use the PAM libraries, or try to make my own library? Is PAM usage some special security risks that should be taken into?

I know that I can authenticate users with python3 spwd class but I dont want to use that, because then I have to run my program with root access.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but I thought I might post this for users to find via Google:

There’s a python3 version of said module which I maintain at https://github.com/leonnnn/python3-simplepam. The naming is different from the python2 version to avoid confusion with an Ubuntu package called python3-pam, but apart from the name, it’s the same as Chris AtLee’s module.

The python3-simplepam module is also available for installation via yum in Fedora 19 and later.

Answer (score 1):

+che

the python pam module you linked to is not python3 compatible.  there are three pam modules that i'm aware of {'pam', 'pypam', 'spypam'}, and none are py3 compatible.

i've modified Chris AtLee's original pam package to work with python3.  cleaning it up a bit before feeding back to him

Comment: any chance you could post your modifications?

Comment: sure @BrianHenk, here; [http://pastebin.com/KNLTUsgT](http://pastebin.com/KNLTUsgT)

Comment: Without knowing FirefighterBlu3's version, I had ported Chris AtLee's module to python3 as well: https://github.com/leonnnn/python3-pam Please note that my version also makes sure to cleanly end the PAM conversation without leaking the PAM context.

Comment: URL of that changed, see my new answer.